# Trying to make a raffle command for my discord bot but keeps returning the winner undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make a raffle command for my discord bot. I kinda have two questions I am trying to make it have a winner based on who reacted to that message here is what I have so far

```
const discord = require("discord.js")
const bot = new discord.Client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) return message.reply("sorry you dont have permission to use this command"); {
      const embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Raffle')
        .addField('React to the message with a thumbs up to enter!', "Time for some fun!")

      message.channel.send(embed).then(function (message) {
        message.react('')

      });

      bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        const user1 = reaction.random

        const embed1 = new discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle('Winner!!')
          .addField(`${user1}`, "you are the winner!!")


        message.channel.send(embed1);

        });

    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "Raffle",
    name: "raffle"
}
```

So user1 keeps returning undefined thanks in advance and by the way I am semi new to JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you set `user1` to `reaction.random`:

```
const user1 = reaction.random
```

`reaction.random` isn't a valid method of [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction), and therefore, when you send the message, `user1` is undefined.

Comment: how would I get a random user that reacted to the message?

Comment: I have also tried reaction.users and it still returns undefined

Comment: I wouldn't use the `messageReactionAdd` at all. That's when a user adds a reaction to the message. How are you planning on picking a winner? Adding a reaction shouldn't cause a winner to be picked. I'd use a command such as `!winner`, which you should check after all the reactions have been made. Then you can fetch the [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions), and get all the reactions. Use [`fetchMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) to find the message. (Store the ID somewhere)